# How to chain a list of binary functions

Tags: r, function, functional-programming

I am interested in the following construction:

Let's suppose I have a list of `n` binary functions and a vector of `n+1` arguments. For arguments sake lets use

```
flist = c(`+`,`-`)
args = 1:3
```

What I would like to do is create the following function call f2(f1(x1,x2),x3) i.e in this example

```
`-`(`+`(1,2),3)
```

where the return value is the vector of cumulative results

```
[1] 3 0
```

I have a solution of the form

```
f = function(x,op,res = NULL){
  if(is.null(res)){
    res = op[[1]](x[1],x[2])
    x = x[-1]
  } else{
    res = c(res,op[[1]](res[length(res)],x[1]))
  }
  if(length(op) == 1) res
  else f(x[-1],op[-1],res)
}
```

such that is gives the correct answer

```
f(x,flist)
[1] 3 0
```

but it doesn't feel particularly R like or elegant. Is there a better way to do this. I suspect that my implementation isn't the most efficient either and so anything that is more efficient would also be of interest.

Any one got any ideas?

Alternatively if relaxing the requirement to have cumulative answers, i.e just the final answer `0` returned, was imposed is there a nice R way to do this? I know I could modify my `f` to deal with this alternative but if there exists a way to do this already I would love to hear about either option.

Edit:

A comment suggested a `for` loop implementation so we could have

```
falt = function(x,op){
  res = numeric(length(op))
  res[1] = op[[1]](x[1],x[2])
  for(i in 2:length(res)) res[i] = op[[i]](res[i-1],x[i+1])
  res
}
```

which does work out more efficient. But I still feel there must be a neater way to do this.

Comment: Why do you use recursion and grow `res`? Just use a `for` loop and pre-allocate res to the final size.

Comment: There was no particular reason for this, I am learning scala currently and so recursion is on my mind a lot. An implementation using a `for` loop does work out ok and is faster, and in R deep recursion is bad so a reasonable suggestion. It feels as though some sort of nice reduce operation should exist for this though. Personal gripe but I also am not a fan of `for` loops in R due to its functional and vectorized nature.
I had also temporarily forgotten about the folly of growing objects in R too.

Comment: would you want to check out the Reduce documentation? search for Iterate...it might help

Comment: There is also a section on Functional Programming in "Advanced R" book by hadley

Comment: Thanks for the comments @chinsoon12. I have just re-read the functional programming section of Hadley's book and whilst I appreciate that applying a list of functions to a given input is relatively trivial I couldn't see how to extend that to what I wanted to do here. I am examining the `?Reduce` docs now and seeing if I can manipulate the Iterate example to achieve my goal.

Comment: Note that a `for` loop (but with some additional bells and whistles) is the core of `Reduce`. If you byte-compile the `for` loop, you'll probably be as fast as any `Reduce` solution (and I don't see how to do this with `Reduce`).

Comment: @Roland cheers, I agree that I can't see how to do it with `base::Reduce`. I guess I am just in search of additional functional functionality within the package universe. I tend to byte-compile most things so agree efficiency wise it is approaching the optimum anyway. I might just have to grin and bear the fact I don't like the loop structure here.

Comment: I've provided an answer that demonstrates the use `Reduce` and a user-defined `comp2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If your functions are already in curried form**, it's a lot easier

```
comp <- function (f) function (g) function (x) f(g(x))

comp2 <- comp (comp) (comp) # if this is confusing, details later

add <- function (x) function (y) y + x
mult <- function (x) function (y) y * x

comp2 (mult) (add) (3) (4) (5)
# 5 * (4 + 3)
# 5 * 7
# 35
```

Because everything is curried, you can apply as many arguments as you want, then apply the rest later

```
compute <- comp2 (mult) (add)
compute (5) (6) (7)
# 7 * (6 + 5)
# 7 * 30
# 210
```

If you have list of binary functions, you can use a left fold (or "reduce") to create an entire sequence

```
identity <- function(x) x
comp <- function (f) function (g) function (x) f(g(x))
comp2 <- comp (comp) (comp)
uncurry <- function (f) function (x,y) f(x)(y)
reduce <- function(f) function(y) function (xs) Reduce(uncurry(f), xs, y)
comp2All <- reduce (comp2) (identity)

# some binary functions to use in our sequence
sub <- function (x) function (y) y - x
add <- function (x) function (y) y + x
mult <- function (x) function (y) y * x

# create a sequence of N binary functions
compute <- comp2All (list(mult, sub, mult, add))

# apply the computation to N+1 args
compute (3) (4) (5) (100) (0.2)
# 0.2 * (100 - (5 * (3 + 4))
# 0.2 * (100 - (5 * 7))
# 0.2 * (100 - 35)
# 0.2 * 65
# => 13
```

So you probably don't like having to apply the computation one argument at a time...

```
# this kind sucks, right?
compute (3) (4) (5) (6) (7)
```

Well we can fix that by making a function that applies a curried function to a list or arguments

```
capply <- reduce (identity)
capply (compute) (3:7)
# 7 * (6 - (5 * (4 + 3)))
# 7 * (6 - (5 * 7))
# 7 * (6 - 35)
# 7 * -29
# => -203
```

---

**If your binary functions are not yet curried:**

You can easily curry a binary function using `curry2`

```
curry2 <- function(f) function(x) function(y) f(x,y)
curry2 (`+`) (3) (4)
# => 7
```

If you have an entire list of binary functions that are not already curried, you can transform the entire list using `map`

```
map <- function (f) function (xs) Map(f,xs)
compute <- comp2All (map (curry2) (list (`*`, `+`, `*`, `+`)))
compute (3) (4) (5) (6) (7)
# 7 * (6 + (5 * (3 + 4)))
# 7 * (6 + (5 * 7))
# 7 * (6 + 35)
# 7 * 41
# => 287
```

---

**comp vs comp2**

Because you want to create a sequence of *binary* functions, I used

```
comp2All <- reduce (comp2) (identity)
```

If you wanted a sequence of *unary* functions, you would use

```
compAll <- reduce (comp) (identity)
```

---

**what is comp2?**

The comp2 definition might seem baffling, but don't let it confuse you

```
comp2 <- comp (comp) (comp)
```

If we were to expand this, we'd first see

```
comp2 <- function (x) comp(comp(x))
```

Upon further expansion (this is a fun exercise for you to do), you should see

```
comp2 <- function (f) function (g) function (x) function (y) f(g(x)(y))
```

Which can be easily understand as the composition of unary function, *f*, with binary function, *g*

Comment: I like the look of this in general and can see how it could be applied to my minimal example. How would one extend this to a general case, let's say the list of `n` functions and `n+1` arguments come from some other mechanism. If `n` is large I don't want to be worrying about what the functions are, or even how long the list is really.

Comment: Are all of the functions binary functions? Are they already curried or can you curry them before hand?

Comment: All functions here are binary yes, but not curried form in general. I tried your final example substituting `f` and `g` for defined binary functions with arguments `x` and `y` but using it as you have above I get missing argument error. I also don't see currently how I would get around typing something like `comp2 (Curry(flist[[1]])) (Curry(flist[[2])) ( .....` which I clearly want to avoid.

Comment: @jamieRowen of course as you add varieties of transformations, it makes sense to create functions that represent each specific transformation. This way the functions are reusable whenever you wish to utilize that transformation. `map` will apply a function `f` to each element in a list, and `reduce` will *fold* a function between each element in a list. See the updated answer for more details. If you have more questions, just ask :)

Comment: sorry it took me so long to come back to this, I got sidetracked with something else and temporarily forgot about this. It also took me a little while to fully digest your answer but I like it.